# rails write xml with builder in action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, builder

I want to use hipay in my site. So i need generate a xml in a action and then send via post to hipay site.

My question is:

How i can create a xml dinamically and then , in the same action, send this xml via post?

Example in my controller

```
def action_generate_xml
  @xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new()
  # I want generate my xml here
  #
  #
  # End generate xml
  #Now i want send My XML via post
  #CODE FOR SEND VIA POST
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the XML data is sitting in an ActiveRecord object then calling to_xml will give you the xml representation of the object.  You can use Ruby's Net:HTTP module to handle the post.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("www.thewebservicedomain.com")
response = http.post("/some/path/here", your_model_object.to_xml)
```

If you want to generate your XML inside your controller (not very Rails-like but you can still do it) use the builder gem:

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
xml.instruct! :xml, :verison => "1.0"   # Or whatever your requirements are
# Consult the Builder gem docs for different ways you can build up your XML, this is just a simple example.
xml.widgets do
  xml.widget do
    xml.serial_number("12345")
    xml.name("First Widget")
    xml.any_other_tag_you_need("Contents of tag")
  end
end
# And now send the request
http = Net::HTTP.new("www.thewebservicedomain.com")
response = http.post("/some/path/here", xml)
```

The second example produces the following XML string and HTTP POST's it to the destination server:

```
<inspect/><?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" verison=\"1.0\"?><widgets><widget><serial_number>12345</serial_number><name>First Widget</name><any_other_tag_you_need>Contents of tag</any_other_tag_you_need></widget></widgets>
```

Comment: Excuse me. I don´t understand. why i save the xml in a ActiveRecord object. I only want to create a xml in action and then send via post. Now i edit my post and write a example. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me again. The xml have other info and tags. I must follow the xml feed of hipay documentation.therefore i must create other tags in xml.

Comment: @maxiperez The example I provided does not save any xml in ActiveRecord, it converts an ActiveRecord object into a String of xml representing the contents of the object.  This is a common Rails idiom.  I will rewrite my answer in a few minutes and give you an example more along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: @maxiperez may I ask you how was your experience with Hipay? easy to integrate with rails? pros / cons ? thx!